# How can I make Selenium to load always the same profile using Marionette in java?

Tags: selenium, profile, firefox-marionette

I've googled arround but found no answer for my question. 
I'd like to have Selenium always opening firefox with the same profile. This is my code:

```
final File pathBinary = new File(properties.getProperty("firefox.webdriver.path"));
final File profileDir = new File("C:\\temp\\profile");
final FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary(pathBinary);
final FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile(profileDir);

System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:/selenium_drivers/firefox/geckodriver.exe");
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, firefoxProfile);

capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);

driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

Could you help?